# Merging csv files into one (columnwise) in Python

Tags: python, csv, merge, analysis

I have many .csv files like this (with one column):
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbxOP.png)

Id like to merge them into one .csv file, so that each of the column will contain one of the csv files data. The headings should be like this (when converted to spreadsheet):
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE5Rq.png) (the first number is the number of minutes extracted from the file name, the second is the first word in the file name behind "export_" in the name, and third is the whole name of the file).

Id like to work in Python.
Can you please someone help me with this? I am new in Python.

Thank you very much.

I tried to join only 2 files, but I have no idea how to do it with more files without writing all down manually. Also, i dont know, how to extract headings from the file names:

```
import pandas as pd 

file_list = ['export_Control 37C 4h_Single Cells_Single Cells_Single Cells.csv', 'export_Control 37C 0 min_Single Cells_Single Cells_Single Cells.csv']
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in file_list:
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], axis=1)
    
print(df)


df.to_csv('output2.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. We understand that you like to have some assistance with the problem you are facing. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Could you show us what you have attempted so far? Also, it seems that the files you are showing in images are spreadsheet documents and not actual CSV files.  Could you elaborate a bit more on the file-content and the file-name?

Comment: [Please also refrain from posting images of text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Format it as a code block instead.

Comment: `pandas.concat()` takes a list of dataframes, You could maintain a global list `l = []` and for each file in your file list you perform `read_csv`, you could append it to `l` and then generate the combined data frame using `pandas.concat()`, You can use `glob` to identify the `csv` files in a specific directory. This assumes you can store all files in memory

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `.csv` files they all have a header and the same number of rows, you can use the code below to put all the `.csv` (single-columned) one besides the other in a single Excel worksheet.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
              
csv_path = r'path_to_the_folder_containing_the_csvs'

csv_files = [file for file in os.listdir(csv_path)]

list_of_dfs=[]
for file in csv_files :
    temp=pd.read_csv(csv_path + '\\' + file, header=0, names=['Header'])
    time_number = pd.DataFrame([[file.split('_')[1].split()[2]]], columns=['Header'])
    file_title = pd.DataFrame([[file.split('_')[1].split()[0]]], columns=['Header'])
    file_name = pd.DataFrame([[file]], columns=['Header'])
    out = pd.concat([time_number, file_title, file_name, temp]).reset_index(drop=True)
    list_of_dfs.append(out)

final= pd.concat(list_of_dfs, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
final.columns = ['Column' + str(col+1) for col in final.columns]
final.to_csv(csv_path + '\output.csv', index=False)
final
```

For example, considering three `.csv` files, running the code above yields to :

##### `>>> Output (in Jupyter)`

[image]

##### `>>> Output (in Excel)`

[image]